# How to treat multiple references to the same work as one citation

Tags: biblatex, citing

On my PhD thesis I'm frequently refering **two versions** of a work. For instance, a translation of Marx's *Eighteenth Brumaire* and the page on the german Marx-Engels *Werke*. Biblatex's `\cites` (or `\footcites`) handles both references just as expected on footnotes with the `authortitle-dw` style.

However, sometimes I quote some paragraph which happens to be the same on **both** subsequent citations. My question is: Can they be treated as if they were actually **one** sigle cite? In the following MWE, the last citation should be *ibid.* (or *loc.cit.*) instead of the repeated references.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,loccittracker=constrict]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{MEW,
author = {Marx, Karl and Engels, Friedrich},
title = {{Werke}},
shorthand = {\textsc{mew}},
}
@book{Marx,
author = {Marx, Karl},
title = {The Eighteenth Brumaire},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

First paragraph\footnote{\cite[23]{Marx}}

Another\footcite[23]{Marx}

Another\footcites{Marx}{MEW}

And so forth\footcites{Marx}{MEW}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of a technical editor, the two works, while identical in the passage you mentioned, are *not* the same. Therefore, both must be cited when quoted passages are the same or very similar, while only the relevant one would be cited when then two versions of a quoted passage are different.

BibLaTeX is doing exactly what it is supposed to do---although perhaps not for the reason(s) you imagined.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. I don't think the OP is suggesting treating the two works as one. Rather, it is asking if the second reference to both works can be treated as another instance of the immediately preceding reference to both works. That is, can `biblatex` treat `\footcites{x}{y}` as a repeat of `\footcites{x}{y}` in the same way that it can be induced to treat `footcite{z}` as a repeat of `\footcite{z}`.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the comment: that was precisely the question I was trying to make, because it looks inconsistent —from a reader viewpoint— to use _sometimes_ `ibid`, whereas in some cases the footnote shows the repeated entries. It looks specially odd something like  1. Aristotle, Politics (greek), 1296a  2. _Ibid_ (or _loc.cit._)  3. Aristotle (english), p.137; Aristotle, Politics 1301b  4. Aristotle (english), p.137; Aristotle, Politics 1301b  instead of  4. _Ibid_

Comment: Ibid. means in the same place, that is, in the reference just cited. Loc. cit. means in the place cited, meaning the same author, work, and page number. There is not, to my knowledge, an abbreviated way to refer to two (or more) cited works in the previous footnote, but I'm most familiar with Chicago and MLA styles. What style are you using?